# Recipe Database extended

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am undergoing a project which this database will be the backend of. I have a few questions with some design aspects I am struggling with.

Here is my design so far:

```
Recipe(id, name, description, time, serving, skill)

Ingredient(id, name, type, description, BaseAmount, AmountType, cost)

RIngredient(RecipeID, IngredientID, AmountNeeded, amount type)

RStep(RecipeID, StepNo, Step description)

Meal(MealID, RecipeName, RecipeServing)

Inventory(InvID, IngredientID, IngredientName, IngredientCost, AmountNeeded)

Timetable(Day, Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner)
```

The meal table, is to be able to store the data into the timetable, but would this design work, as in future if the meal has more than one serving when its cooked, the meal should be stored and eaten the next day or 2 max. So making effective use of ingredients.
The Inventory is to keep track of what has been bought and to calculate the leftover ingredients. This is so if some ingredients are left over the user can be notified so they don't have to buy as much next time round.

I would also like to be able to add additional ingredients or remove them for that instance of recipe. Would this be done as sql statements delte/update or would a seperate table be needed.

Any comments would be greatly appreciate on the design or anything you might think would work better.

Comment: I woudl add/remove rows in the RIngredient table

Comment: One thing to think about is that recipes sometimes require the same ingredient twice (e.g my pancakes require 400g butter, plus 50g for the pan)

Comment: @RiggsFolly But would this be a permanent addition to the recipe then? the database is going to be used by multiple users so each user may have different preferences?

Comment: @Strawberry Good point! hadn't considered this, could we not just add a purpose attribute in RIngredient which would justify if it was for the recipe or preparation?

Comment: Yes, that might be one way. So your UNIQUE KEY might be (recipe_id,ingredient_id,preparation_flag)

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks! ignoring the timetable part as i think this would be best done with queries. Do you have any thoughts on the inventory or will this method work?

Comment: Well, I don't think you would store ingredient_name, but apart from that, it might be right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Recipe` produces some number of servings -- is that what you mean by `serving`?

You can make a "double recipe" or, perhaps, a "half recipe", so something needs to specify that 'factor'.

So, you need another table that indicates "making a recipe"; I'll call it `Batch`, with the `RecipeId` `factor`, `datetime`.

A `Meal` is composed of multiple things, so you need a many-to-many mapping table between `Meal` and each of the Batches involved in the Meal.

Can't you freeze the leftovers?  Of so "a day or 2" is mostly irrelevant.  But you will have an inventory of `Servings` sitting in the freezer.

I don't know where you are headed with `Timetable`; most of that info can/should be in `Meal`.

Have fun converting "cups" of flower when subtracting from your 5 pounds of flour in `Inventory`.

Comment: although i do like the idea of the double and half servings. I was only going to use the servings for display, and on the front end of the db i could do calculations on the recipe ingredients to create such servings? But I'd be open to use this method, but I'm slightly lost with the Batch table.

With the meal i was heading in the direction of A Recipe makes up a meal which is then used to generate the timetable? but yes the day or 2 is irrelevant forgot we had freezers haha. should I have a Frozen flag somewhere to indicate?

Luckily I'm from the UK so all that will be dealt with in grams. :)

Comment: Thanks for a very constructive comment though, I'm a software student so I'm still new to databases but this is an extra curriculum project to get me going.

Comment: I almost threw an ER lecture at you -- Think about your "Entities" (ingredient, meal, ...); each will be a table.  Then think about "Relationships" between Entities.  I did not because "time" and "leftovers", etc get messy.

Comment: Suggest as a starter, you leave out leftovers and other complexities.  Focus on some of the basics - there will be enough things to challenge you.  Then augment the schema to handle the other 'features' of your project.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I understand these basic fundamentals - I'm half way through my database module. The project I have in mind is probably much bigger than i can handle so great advice. I'll get the basic functionalities of the database running smooth then extend later on. No doubt you'll see me posting here along the way. Thanks for your advice